# modal pop suppressing firing of event in codebehind of form

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I've got a .net website, c# codebehind. I've got a LinkButton control which, when clicked, I want to fire off some code on the backend. However I'm also triggering a modal pop confirmation to show up on the front end by clicking on the button. The modal pop fires, but its suppressing ever firing off the code on the backend. Can someone lend me a hand on figuring out what's going on?

front:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbWishlist" runat="server" rel="#wishlist" CssClass="modalInput" onclick="lbWishlist_Click"><img src="images/products_add_wishlist.jpg" border="0" /></asp:LinkButton>

<div class="modal" id="wishlist">
<h2>Succesfully added!</h2>
This item has been successfully added to your wishlist.
<br /><br />
<button type="button" class="close" style="width:70px;height:20px;border:1px solid #a2a2a2;color:#333333;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:9px;"> Close </button>
</div>
```

Codebehind:

```
 protected void lbWishlist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //some code
        }
```

modal script:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var triggers = $(".modalInput").overlay({

            // some mask tweaks suitable for modal dialogs
            mask: {
                color: '#ebecff',
                loadSpeed: 200,
                opacity: 0.9
            },

            closeOnClick: false
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Please post the code that shows the modal pop-up.

Comment: Sorry, just edited it with the modal script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't that be a click event that you need to tie your link button to? In this case, you are showing the dialog on overlay. Button is never clicked. So server event hardly gets fired.

So, if you are already comfortable with the modal dialog appearing, upon clicking Yes on the confirm dialog you can use the below code to have the server event triggered.

```
$(".modalInput").trigger("click");
```

Comment: Never thought of tying the event to the button in the modal. Thanks.